# Unable to install TSExact extension for PSQL 10.1 on Windows 10

Tags: postgresql

I am tring to install the above extension but unable to do so. The extension is available at: https://github.com/postgrespro/tsexact

Can someone help installing in windows environment.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! When asking questions, please provide as much detail about the problem as you can. Such as any errors you get. The environment you are using.. etc..

Comment: https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/

Comment: I am using Windows and PSQL Version 10.1. It is an extra extension that can be used with PSQL for full text search. I have provided the github link for this extension but there is no procedure to build it for windows.